# How to calculate the probability that an event has a probability of N%?

Tags: probability

For example I have a sequence of results (0 or 1) of an event:

```
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 (<-- 5/5)
```

I want to say that the probability is 50%/50%. But I can not because I do not know for sure. But this probability is more probable than others:

```
50%/50% - .5 ^ 5 * .5 ^ 5 = ~0.001
60%/40% - .6 ^ 5 * .4 ^ 5 = ~0.0008
90%/10% - .9 ^ 5 * .1 ^ 5 = ~0.000006
```

So how to calculate probability that the phrase "The probability of getting 1 (and 0 too) is 50%" is true? What if I do not know that result can be only 1 or 0?

Answer (score 0):

Basically a series of $n$ events can be represented univocally with a binary number:

$$\underbrace{1...1}_{n_1}\underbrace{0...0}_{n_0}$$

If the probability of getting $1$ was $N$, the probability of getting a sequence with $n_1$ cipher $1$ and $n_2$ cipher $2$ would be:

$${n\choose{n_1}}N^{n_1}(1-N)^{n-n_1}$$

However the probability $N$ can assume infinitely many values($ N \in \Bbb{R}$). So this question hasn't meaning in classic probability. You can say however which probability is more probable by calculating the maximum of the equation above.